# Simple macros for book page headers

Tags: header-footer

This is a repost of yesterday's question. Forgot to box code;
my apologies!
Objective: build simple macros to specify
page headers for my first LaTeX book.

Task 1: retrieve chapter, section and subsection names with low level macros.
Code:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\Chaptermark\chaptermark%
\def\chaptermark#1{\def\Chaptername{#1}\Chaptermark{#1}}%
\let\Sectionmark\sectionmark%
\def\sectionmark#1{\def\Sectionname{#1}\Sectionmark{#1}}%
\let\Subsectionmark\subsectionmark%
\def\subsectionmark#1{\def\Subsectionname{#1}\Subsectionmark{#1}}
```

Quick check:

```
\chapter{First Chapter}\label{ch:first}
This is Chapter~\ref{ch:first} with title `\Chaptername''.
\section{First Section}\label{sec:first}
This is Section~\ref{sec:first} with title ``\Sectionname''.
\subsection{First Subsection}\label{subsec:first}
This is Subsection~\ref{subsec:first} with title ``\Subsectionname''.
\newpage
\chapter{Second Chapter}\label{ch:second}
This is Chapter~\ref{ch:second} with title ``\Chaptername''.
\section{First Section of Chapter 2}\label{sec:second}
This is Section~\ref{sec:second} with title ``\Sectionname''.
\subsection{First Subsection of Section 1 of Chapter 2}\label{subsec:second}
This is Subsection~\ref{subsec:second} with title ``\Subsectionname''.
\newpage
\chapter{Third Chapter}\label{ch:third}
This is Chapter~\ref{ch:third} with title ``\Chaptername''.
\section{First Section of Chapter 3}\label{sec:third}
This is Section~\ref{sec:third} with title ``\Sectionname''.
\subsection{First Subsection of Section 1 of Chapter 3}\label{subsec:third}
This is Subsection~\ref{subsec:third} with title ``\Subsectionname''.
\end{document}
```

Works fine (of course labels will be far more complex
in the book).

Task 2: specify header and footer. Target format:

even pages:  RJ "Chapter#": chapter title.

odd  pages:  LJ "Chapter#.Section#: section title.

using the above-extracted titles. Question:
should I redo \markleft and \markright using \def?
Or is there a simpler way?

In PlainTeX all of this was duck soup in 1986,
6 lines of code. But I am not that familiar with LaTeX,
except for the biblios macros, which I had to
tweak a decade ago for a review article.

Comment: you can edit posts, no need to make new question

Comment: Why do you want the subsection titles, as you don't use them in the headers?

Comment: Tried this code in TeXShop on a Mac.  Stops immediately with a missing docstyle error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, much simpler than your MWE.

```
% bookheadersprob.tex  SE 647340

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{comment}    %%% don't need next bunch of code
\let\Chaptermark\chaptermark%
\def\chaptermark#1{\def\Chaptername{#1}\Chaptermark{#1}}%
\let\Sectionmark\sectionmark%
\def\sectionmark#1{\def\Sectionname{#1}\Sectionmark{#1}}%
\let\Subsectionmark\subsectionmark%
\def\subsectionmark#1{\def\Subsectionname{#1}\Subsectionmark{#1}}
\end{comment}

%% remove \chaptername beforethe number in the headings
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. #1}{}}

%%% define \...name (but only because they occur in the MWE)
\newcommand{\Chaptername}{Chapter} %%%%\chaptername
\newcommand{\Sectionname}{Section}
\newcommand{\Subsectionname}{Subsection}

  
\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}\label{ch:first}
This is Chapter~\ref{ch:first} with title `\Chaptername''.
\newpage
\section{First Section}\label{sec:first}
This is Section~\ref{sec:first} with title ``\Sectionname''.
\subsection{First Subsection}\label{subsec:first}
This is Subsection~\ref{subsec:first} with title ``\Subsectionname''.

\newpage

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\newpage
\chapter{Second Chapter}\label{ch:second}
This is Chapter~\ref{ch:second} with title ``\Chaptername''.
\section{First Section of Chapter 2}\label{sec:second}
This is Section~\ref{sec:second} with title ``\Sectionname''.
\subsection{First Subsection of Section 1 of Chapter 2}\label{subsec:second}
This is Subsection~\ref{subsec:second} with title ``\Subsectionname''.
\newpage
\chapter{Third Chapter}\label{ch:third}
This is Chapter~\ref{ch:third} with title ``\Chaptername''.
\section{First Section of Chapter 3}\label{sec:third}
This is Section~\ref{sec:third} with title ``\Sectionname''.
\subsection{First Subsection of Section 1 of Chapter 3}\label{subsec:third}
This is Subsection~\ref{subsec:third} with title ``\Subsectionname''.
\end{document}
```

As far as I could make out you did not want "Chapter" to appear in the headers. The above does that by changing  the `\chaptermark`, ignoring what you have tried in your MWE.

You say that it would have been "duck soup" in PlainTex requiring only 6 lines of code. The duck must have been rather tough as using LaTeX it only requires 1 line of code. --- GOM

**EDIT**

For more information read sections 4.3.4 *LaTeX mark commands* and 4.4 *Page styles* in *the LaTeX Companion* by Frank Mittlebach and Michel Goosens, Second Edition, Addison-Wesley, 2004, ISBN 0-201-362999-6.